# Identifying users based on smartphone data (Google)

Tags: machine-learning, google

I've heard that Google has now a technique to identify users based on the smartphone touch input (how the user is using the phone). I have found nothing about that online. Is there a paper or some article available explaining how this is done (e.g. what features are used)?

Comment: just kidding but maybe use a different search engine ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even I was unable to find a paper on sucha topic by Google. But, I can discuss some features which Google might be using to uniquely identify its users based on smartphone data.

1. **Fingerprint scanning**: One of the preliminary methods of scanning users as the fingerprint is unique to every individual. Also, most devices are now equipped with a fingerprint scanner.
2. **Home location**: The Google account also keeps a track of the user's home location which can't be directly used to identify a user, but could be an important feature.
3. **Data Personalization**: Suppose a user has habit of viewing videos, blogs and websites related with the top tag "artificial intellgence". This personalized information could be used to track down a user.

> Data persoanlization could be applied to apps, videos and websites with which the user interacts. This data will be super complex and probably unique to each individual.

4. **Device Usage**: Every individual likes to personalize and use his/her device in their own way. Android 9 had this feature of tracking apps which are most used by the user and also at which times. This is another great factor for identification.
5. **Preliminary device details**: IP address, the device's model, Android version, account password are also stored with the Google account.

*The above features could be brought together to uniquely identify users as they provide information in different dimensions regarding the user.*

The weaker features ( Data personalization, device usage ) can be used with the powerful features ( IP address, passwords ) to uniquely identify a particular user.

**All the above information was not mentioned in any paper.**

Hope this helps. :-)